# How to create a custom pop up view with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, popup

So I am working on a simple app, where I use a table view. This table view displays the name of "players". But in order for me to add players in the table view, I want a pop up window to be displayed with a text field where you provide the name.

Now I have been reading about creating a xib or nib file, but I am not sure how to "load" the pop up window.

What's the best approach to this?

Looks like this:

[image: Pop up View]

[image]

Comment: Design your popup in storyboard, then use this 3rd party to show it up: https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you'd create an custom `UIView` with all respected object needed, from your Controller's viewDidLoad() you'll hide it.

```
customView.hidden = true
```

Whenever your user wants to perform some action or task, you unhide it and once the user finished then **hide it again** or **remove from the superView**.

```
customView.hidden = false
```

> Below there is some code to help you start

```
    private var customView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customView.hidden = true
    }

    private func loadCustomViewIntoController() {
         let customViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, witdh: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 200)
         customView = UIView(frame: customViewFrame)

         view.addSubview(customView)

         customView.hidden = false

        // any other objects should be tied to this view as superView 
        // for example adding this okayButton

        let okayButtonFrame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
        let okayButton = UIButton(frame: okayButtonFrame )

         // here we are adding the button its superView
         customView.addSubview(okayButton)

         okayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didPressButtonFromCustomView:), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

    }


    func didPressButtonFromCustomView(sender:UIButton) {
         // do whatever you want
         // make view disappears again, or remove from its superview
    }


    @IBAction func rateButton(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
        // this barButton is located at the top of your tableview navigation bar
        // when it pressed make sure you remove any other activities that were on the screen, for example dismiss a keyboard 

          loadCustomViewIntoController()
    }
```

Check it out this [github project](https://github.com/LamourBt/ViewCoordinator), It's closed to be production ready, it gives you a better way to deal (present and dismiss) with UIViews

> If you only want the player's name then use a `UIAlertController` containing a textfield

Comment: I've worked on that option, problem is that on the story board is kind of difficult to implement since I am working with a tableview and there is no where to place the "UIView". Or at least I don't know how to do that part. If I add a view to the top, it's a view for the header, or at the bottom is a view for the footer. I will add a screenshot to the original post of what I mean.

Comment: you dont need to drag the UIView on top of the tableview... you could create the UIView via code do you want to see an example ?

Comment: Please.. I've been wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Perfect thank you.. I will try to do it this way. The hard part I see to this is that the design of my custom pop up, is kind of specific lol So I will have to play around a bit to figure it out. If you look at my screenshot, you will notice what I am saying. I want it to look like that, I guess I have to play with the UIView properties. Never done that, but there is always a first time. I also try to up vote your answer, but someone just down voted my question and it brought me down to 13 on reputation and won't let me up vote till i get to 15 again.

Comment: if you might have a question just go to the chat look for this room "CheckerHelp" just send a message

Comment: I will when I get enough reputation points lol someone just down voted my question, and I can't even up vote your answer since I am below 15 now.

Answer (score 20):

**In storyboard**

- In storyboard create one UIViewController and design it according to your requirement.
- Set custom class as anotherViewController and Storyboard_ID as another_view_sid
- Create one new Cocoa Touch Class as anotherViewController and subclass of UIVIewController

**In viewController**

```
    let popvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "another_view_sid") as! anotherViewController

    self.addChildViewController(popvc)

    popvc.view.frame = self.view.frame

    self.view.addSubview(popvc.view)

    popvc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

**In anotherViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        showAnimate()
    }
}

@IBAction func Close_popupView(_ sender: Any) {
    removeAnimate()
}

func showAnimate()
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
}

func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(finished : Bool) in
        if(finished)
        {
            self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This 3rd party EzPopup (https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup) can help you show it up. Just design your popup in storyboard, then init it.

```
// init YourViewController
let contentVC = ...

// Init popup view controller with content is your content view controller
let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: contentVC, popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)

// show it by call present(_ , animated:) method from a current UIViewController
present(popupVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: For anyone that comes alone, [PopupDialog](https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog) is a nice and easy-to-use library for popup window in iOS. It is actively maintained as in 2018.

Comment: @ Yuan Fu, But in this library I am trying to give custom height, and I did not find any way to do this yet.

Comment: @Monusingh with EzPopup, you can set custom width height for popup

Comment: EzPopup worked me perfectly. It can resize any viewController easily without reside in Xib, that's nice job.